# RadScheduler not filter Appointments

Tags: .net, telerik, telerik-scheduler

I am using RadScheduler that works fine but i cant filter appointment after selection of checkbox  and also date is not selected if change the calendar date sorry if i make a mistake in question and advance thanks for helping

my code is here

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sds" Namespace="Telerik.Web.SessionDS" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
    <title>ASP.NET scheduler examples | RadScheduler control demo</title>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
          //<![CDATA[
        var categoryNames = new Array();
        var scheduler = null;
        var calendar1 = null;
        var SchedulerNavigationCompleteAlreadyOccurred = false;

        function pageLoad() {

            scheduler = $find('<%=RadScheduler1.ClientID %>');
            calendar1 = $find('<%=RadCalendar1.ClientID %>');
        }
        function rebindScheduler() {

            var scheduler = $find('<%=RadScheduler1.ClientID %>');

            scheduler.rebind();
        }

        function OnClientAppointmentsPopulating(sender, eventArgs) {
            addSelectedCategoriesToArray(categoryNames);
            eventArgs.get_schedulerInfo().CategoryNames = categoryNames;
            categoryNames = new Array(); //clear the array
        }

        function addSelectedCategoriesToArray(categoryNamesArray) {
            var $ = $telerik.$;
            var categoryPanelBar = $find('<%=RadPanelBar1.ClientID %>');
            $(':checkbox:checked', categoryPanelBar.get_element()).each(function () {
                categoryNames.push($(this).attr('name'));
            });
        }

        function OnClientAppointmentWebServiceInserting(sender, args) {
            //set a default Calendar resource
            if (args.get_appointment().get_resources().get_count() == 0) {
                var defaultCalendarResource = sender.get_resources().getResourceByTypeAndKey("Calendar", 1);
                args.get_appointment().get_resources().add(defaultCalendarResource);
            }
        }

        function OnCalendar1DateSelected(sender, args) {
            var scheduler = $find('<%=RadScheduler1.ClientID %>');

            var selectedDateTriplet = sender.get_selectedDates()[0];
            if (selectedDateTriplet) {
                var selectedDate = new Date(selectedDateTriplet[0], selectedDateTriplet[1] - 1, selectedDateTriplet[2]);
                scheduler.set_selectedDate(selectedDate);


            }
        }

        function OnCalendar1ViewChanged(sender, eventArgs) {

            var dateTriplet = sender.get_focusedDate();

            if (!SchedulerNavigationCompleteAlreadyOccurred) {
                var selectedDate = new Date(dateTriplet[0], dateTriplet[1] - 1, dateTriplet[2]);
                scheduler.set_selectedDate(selectedDate);
            }
            SchedulerNavigationCompleteAlreadyOccurred = false;
        }

        function OnClientNavigationComplete(sender, args) {
            SchedulerNavigationCompleteAlreadyOccurred = true;
            var selectedDate = sender.get_selectedDate();
            calendar1.navigateToDate([selectedDate.format("yyyy"), selectedDate.format("MM"), selectedDate.format("dd")]);
        }
          //]]>
    </script>
    <telerik:RadSplitter runat="server" ID="RadSplitter1" Skin="Sunset" PanesBorderSize="0"
        Width="1000" Height="600">
        <telerik:RadPane runat="Server" ID="leftPane" Width="220" Scrolling="None">
            <telerik:RadSplitter runat="server" ID="RadSplitter2" Skin="Sunset" Orientation="Horizontal"
                Width="100%">
                <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane1" runat="server" Width="220" Height="200">
                    <telerik:RadCalendar runat="server" ID="RadCalendar1" Skin="Metro" EnableMultiSelect="false"
                        DayNameFormat="FirstTwoLetters" EnableNavigation="true" EnableMonthYearFastNavigation="true">
                        <ClientEvents OnDateSelected="OnCalendar1DateSelected" OnCalendarViewChanged="OnCalendar1ViewChanged" />
                    </telerik:RadCalendar>
                </telerik:RadPane>
                <telerik:RadSplitBar ID="RadSplitBar1" runat="server" EnableResize="false" />
                <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane2" runat="server">
                    <telerik:RadPanelBar runat="server" ID="RadPanelBar1" Skin="Sunset" Width="100%"
                        ExpandAnimation-Type="None" CollapseAnimation-Type="None" ExpandMode="SingleExpandedItem">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadPanelItem runat="server" Text="My Calendars" Expanded="true">
                                <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadPanelItem runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="rpCheckBoxPanel">
                                                <div class="qsf-chk-personal">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input id="chkPersonal" type="checkbox" title="National Plans" onclick="rebindScheduler()"
                                                            value="National Plans" checked="checked" name="National Plans" />
                                                        <span>National Plans</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="qsf-chk-work">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input id="chkWork" type="checkbox" title="My Co-ops" onclick="rebindScheduler()"
                                                            value="My Co-ops" checked="checked" name="My Co-ops" />
                                                        <span>My Co-ops</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Group" OnClick="Button1_Click"
                                                Icon-PrimaryIconCssClass="qsf-btn-group" />
                                            <span title="This button Groups RadScheduler by its Resources creating a separate calendar for each resource item and situating the appropriate appointments there."
                                                class="qsf-btn-hint">?</span>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:RadPanelItem>
                                </Items>
                            </telerik:RadPanelItem>
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadPanelBar>
                </telerik:RadPane>
            </telerik:RadSplitter>
        </telerik:RadPane>
        <telerik:RadSplitBar runat="server" ID="RadSplitBar2" CollapseMode="Forward" EnableResize="false" />
        <telerik:RadPane runat="Server" ID="rightPane" Scrolling="None">
            <telerik:RadScheduler runat="server" ID="RadScheduler1" DataEndField="End" Skin="Vista"
                DataKeyField="ID" DataRecurrenceField="RecurrenceRule" DataRecurrenceParentKeyField="RecurrenceParentID"
                DataSourceID="SchedulerDataSource" DataDescriptionField="Description" Height="700px"
                DataStartField="Start" DataSubjectField="Subject" DayStartTime="08:00:00" DayEndTime="21:00:00"
                FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" LastDayOfWeek="Friday" EnableDescriptionField="true"
                AppointmentStyleMode="Default" OnClientAppointmentsPopulating="OnClientAppointmentsPopulating"
                OnClientAppointmentWebServiceInserting="OnClientAppointmentWebServiceInserting"
                OnClientNavigationComplete="OnClientNavigationComplete">
                <%--     <WebServiceSettings Path="App_Code/SchedulerWebService.vb" ResourcePopulationMode="ServerSide" />--%>
                <AdvancedForm Modal="true"></AdvancedForm>
                <TimelineView UserSelectable="false"></TimelineView>
                <ResourceTypes>
                    <telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="RoomsDataSource" ForeignKeyField="RoomID" KeyField="ID"
                        Name="Room" TextField="RoomName" />
                </ResourceTypes>
                <ResourceStyles>
                    <%--AppointmentStyleMode must be explicitly set to Default (see above) otherwise setting BackColor/BorderColor
                                   will switch the appointments to Simple rendering (no rounded corners and gradients)--%>
                    <telerik:ResourceStyleMapping Type="Room" Text="National Plans" ApplyCssClass="blue-border" />
                    <telerik:ResourceStyleMapping Type="Room" Text="My Co-ops" ApplyCssClass="green-border" />
                </ResourceStyles>
                <ResourceHeaderTemplate>
                    <div class="rsResourceHeader<%# Eval("Text") %>">
                        <%# Eval("Text")%>
                    </div>
                </ResourceHeaderTemplate>
                <TimeSlotContextMenuSettings EnableDefault="true" />
                <AppointmentContextMenuSettings EnableDefault="true" />
                <Localization HeaderWeek="Work week" />
            </telerik:RadScheduler>
            <%--        <telerik:RadScheduler ID="RadScheduler1" runat="server" DataEndField="End" DataKeyField="ID"
                DataRecurrenceField="RecurrenceRule" DataRecurrenceParentKeyField="RecurrenceParentID"
                DataSourceID="SchedulerDataSource" DataDescriptionField="Description" Height="700px"
                DataStartField="Start" DataSubjectField="Subject" Skin="Windows7">
                <AdvancedForm Modal="true"></AdvancedForm>
                <TimelineView UserSelectable="false"></TimelineView>
                <ResourceTypes>
                    <telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="RoomsDataSource" ForeignKeyField="RoomID" KeyField="ID"
                        Name="Room" TextField="RoomName" />
                </ResourceTypes>
                <ResourceStyles>
                    <telerik:ResourceStyleMapping Type="Calendar" Text="VIP" BorderColor="#abd962" />
                    <telerik:ResourceStyleMapping Type="Calendar" Text="VVIP" BorderColor="#25a0da" />
                </ResourceStyles>
                <ResourceHeaderTemplate>
                    <div class="rsResourceHeader<%# Eval("Text") %>">
                        <%# Eval("Text") %>
                    </div>
                </ResourceHeaderTemplate>
                <TimeSlotContextMenuSettings EnableDefault="true" />
                <AppointmentContextMenuSettings EnableDefault="true" />
                <Localization HeaderWeek="Work week" />
            </telerik:RadScheduler>--%>
        </telerik:RadPane>
    </telerik:RadSplitter>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <%--<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadScheduler1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadScheduler1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>--%>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadScheduler1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SchedulerDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SchedulerConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Appointments] WHERE [ID] = @ID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Appointments] ([Subject], [Start], [End], [RecurrenceRule], [RecurrenceParentID], [Description], [RoomID]) VALUES (@Subject, @Start, @End, @RecurrenceRule, @RecurrenceParentID, @Description, @RoomID)"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Subject], [Start], [End], [RecurrenceRule], [RecurrenceParentID], [Description], [RoomID] FROM [Appointments]"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Appointments] SET [Subject] = @Subject, [Start] = @Start, [End] = @End, [RecurrenceRule] = @RecurrenceRule, [RecurrenceParentID] = @RecurrenceParentID, [Description] = @Description, [RoomID] = @RoomID WHERE [ID] = @ID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Subject" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Start" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="End" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RecurrenceRule" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RecurrenceParentID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RoomID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Subject" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Start" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="End" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RecurrenceRule" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RecurrenceParentID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RoomID" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RoomsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SchedulerConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [RoomName] FROM [Rooms]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of Server-Side binding as in this case you can use the AppoinmentDataBound event as it is done in this example- http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/resources/defaultcs.aspx